# C++17 testing for data-member SFINAE: gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17, sfinae

I have simple code snippet where I'm trying to test for a data-member:

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T0 >
using is_data_member = std::bool_constant< std::is_same_v< std::void_t< T0 >, void > >;

template< typename U,
          std::add_pointer_t< std::enable_if_t< 
            is_data_member< decltype( std::declval< U >().a ) >::value
          > > = nullptr >
auto test() {}

struct A { int a; };
struct B {};

int main() {
  static_assert( is_data_member< decltype( std::declval< A >().a ) >::value );
  // #1: static_assert below fails in both gcc and clang. 
  // static_assert( is_data_member< decltype( std::declval< B >().a ) >::value );

  test< A >();
  // #2: test< B >() below fails in gcc, but does not fail in clang?
  test< B >();
}
```

With `gcc` everything works as I would expect: compilation error for both `#1` and `#2`.
But with `clang` only `#1` fails to compile, while `#2` does compile.
Please, see for yourself: [code on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/_AzTzr).

So the question is, basically, what's going on? I tend to think that `clang` has slightly better compliance with the Standard in comparison to `gcc`, but in this case it looks to me that `clang` is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a (fixed) Clang bug. It behaves as expected with Clang trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/Gmb9oy

Comment: @walnut thanks a bunch. Wow, didn't expect to see such a (trivial?) clang bug in 2020... Do you want to make your comment an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: It isn't that trivial. The behavior of substitution in arguments of alias templates was changed at the end of 2014 with [CWG issue 1558](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558). The change for this particular case must have been overlooked when that defect report was implemented in clang. It works fine if you use the more common `typename = std::enable_if_t<...>` syntax.

Comment: Btw. `is_data_member` does not work as you seem to expect it to. `decltype( std::declval<B>().a )` is already a substitution failure in the context where it is used. So `is_data_member` is always `std::true_type` when it doesn't fail. You can just as well use `void_t` directly.

Comment: Yeah, `is_data_member` is never `std::false_type`. I'm still trying to figure out how to make it work. It does serve he purpose, but I want to have `is_data_member::value == false` and then fail via `enable_if`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Clang. With current Clang trunk the substitution fails as is expected.

I guess this was resolved with [this bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43547), according to which arguments of alias templates (such as `is_data_member`) were not treated correctly during substitution if they appeared in type specifiers of non-type template parameters.